# Forwarding External Ports to specific internal machines depending on the service type

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding, port

I currently run a web server with SSL on port 443. I also want to run a SSTP server so I can VPN into my network remotely. This service also used default port 443 and I would like to keep it that way. Each server runs on a different machine.

My question is, is there a way to route inbound external traffic on port 443 to its respective server based on whether its a SSTP connection or a web connection based on the data type? Can they be sererated by hostname? For example, if a user connects on example.com or www.example.com they will be forwarded to the internal web server, but if they connect on vpn.example.com they will be forwarded to the VPN server.

Comment: You can do that with [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)